# How much does friendship raise exactly with TM method?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I read on the internet that alternating two TMs on a pokemon should raise friendship pretty fast and should give maximum friendship in 5 to 10 minutes. Well, I think I'm over 15 minutes and my Munchlax still doesn't evolve after leveling up. I must say that I don't have Soothe Bell or Luxury Ball on him though.

Are there some hard numbers of with what value the friendship is raised after each new move learned?

As far as I understand most pokemon start at 70 and will evolve with lvl up at 220 or higher.

So, how much does the friendship raise exactly in these situations:

- while holding Soothe Bell
- while being in a Luxury Ball
- holding Soothe Bell and in a Luxury Ball
- without Soothe Bell or Luxury Ball

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, I'm taking 6th gen as example because data is not out yet, but there are no reason to think that it has changed.

> If a Pokémon is caught in a **Luxury Ball** or is holding a **Soothe
>   Bell**, all friendship-raising events will increase the Pokémon's
>   friendship value by an extra point; friendship-lowering events are not
>   affected.
>
> If the Pokémon's friendship is increased at the location of where it
>   was met, an extra +1 friendship is added to the boost.
>
> Note that holding a *Soothe Bell* will still apply a rounded-down
>   multiplier of 1.5 after applying the extra bonus from location and
>   *Luxury Ball*, if applicable.

More info on friendship-raising events on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship).

---

Regarding the TM method, according to [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/5e37gz/psa_an_easier_way_to_increase_happiness/):

> Anyone know by how much per use?
>   Apparently not much. Literally TM spammed for like 45 mins and my Eevee still won't evolve.

So it doesn't seem a "pretty fast" way to raise friendship. Or even untrue.

Answer (score 2):

The TM thing is a scam, it does not actually work.